# Error: :0: error: (499) undefined symbol:

Tags: pic, undefined-symbol, xc8

I'm trying to use a globalVar.h to get my main.c cleaner and tidied up.
But I get many errors that me and my colleagues can't understand or solve.

Would some please be so kind and give me a hint what I could have done wrong?

I'm using MPLAB X IDE 3.60 and MPLAB XC8 for my PIC12F1572.

```
// main.c

#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "globalVar.h"

void SDiagnose(sd_state_t SD_STATE);

void main(void)
{
    // Initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

    while (1)
    {
        if (gFlag_SDAktiv)          // Selbstdiagnose wird alle 180 Sekunden aktiviert
        {
            switch(gCnt_SD)
            {
            case 180:
                SD_STATE = START;
                SDiagnose(SD_STATE);                     //SD-PIN auf LOW ziehen, Laden starten
                break;

            case 190:
                SD_STATE = STARTMESSEN;
                SDiagnose(SD_STATE);               //Messung des Wertes während des Ladens und der Rekuperation starten
                break;

            default:
                break;

            }
        }   
    }
}

void SDiagnose(sd_state_t SD_STATE)
{ 
    switch(SD_STATE) 
    {
        case START:
            PIN_SDIAGNOSE_SetDigitalOutput();
            PIN_SDIAGNOSE_SetLow();
            break;

        case STARTMESSEN: 
            ADC1_StartConversion();
            break;

        default:  
            break;      
    }
}
```

---

```
//globalVar.h

#include <xc.h> // include processor files - each processor file is guarded.  


#ifndef EXTERN
    #define EXTERN extern
#endif


typedef enum {START, STOP, STARTMESSEN, MESSEN1, MESSEN2, FREIGEBEN} 
        sd_state_t;



EXTERN volatile sd_state_t SD_STATE;

EXTERN volatile unsigned char gFlag_AdcReady = 0;

EXTERN volatile unsigned char gFlag_SDAktiv = 0;

EXTERN volatile unsigned char gCnt_SD = 0;



#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */



#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

---

```
//tmr1.c

#include <xc.h>
#include "tmr1.h"

#include "../globalVar.h"

// ...
// MCC-Generated standard code..
// ...

void TMR1_DefaultInterruptHandler(void){
    // add your TMR1 interrupt custom code
    // or set custom function using TMR1_SetInterruptHandler()

    gCnt_SD++;


    if (gCnt_SD == 180)
    {
        gFlag_SDAktiv = 1;
    }
```

---

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "adc1.h"
#include "mcc.h"

#include "../globalVar.h"

void ADC1_ISR(void)
{
    // Clear the ADC interrupt flag
    PIR1bits.ADIF = 0;

    gFlag_AdcReady = 1; // Flag setzen, AD-Wandlung abgeschlossen



}
```

---

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 125ms)
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AS/Desktop/MPLAB_Projekte/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/AS/Desktop/MPLAB_Projekte/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/mcc.p1  mcc_generated_files/mcc.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.p1  mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.p1  mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/tmr0.p1  mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/tmr1.p1  mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/main.p1  main.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=12F1572 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/mcc_generated_files/adc1.p1  mcc_generated_files/adc1.c 
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:17: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:19: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:21: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
globalVar.h:17: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
globalVar.h:19: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:87: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
globalVar.h:21: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:96: warning: (2030) a data pointer cannot be used to hold the address of a function
pointer to function with no arguments returning void -> pointer to void
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:118: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:179: warning: (2029) a function pointer cannot be used to hold the address of data
pointer to void -> pointer to function with no arguments returning void
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:17: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:19: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:21: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:113: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:119: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:140: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:17: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:19: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/../globalVar.h:21: warning: (339) initializer in extern declaration
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:75: warning: (373) implicit signed to unsigned conversion
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:90: warning: (2030) a data pointer cannot be used to hold the address of a function
pointer to function with no arguments returning void -> pointer to void
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:133: warning: (2029) a function pointer cannot be used to hold the address of data
pointer to void -> pointer to function with no arguments returning void
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.42\bin\xc8.exe"  --chip=12F1572 -G -mdist/default/production/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.map  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"      --memorysummary dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -odist/default/production/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.elf  build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/adc1.p1 build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/mcc.p1 build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.p1 build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.p1 build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/tmr1.p1 build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/tmr0.p1 build/default/production/main.p1     
Microchip MPLAB XC8 C Compiler (Free Mode) V1.42
Build date: Apr 12 2017
Part Support Version: 1.42
Copyright (C) 2017 Microchip Technology Inc.
License type: Node Configuration

:: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:103: advisory: (1510) non-reentrant function "_ADC1_StartConversion" appears in multiple call graphs and has been duplicated by the compiler
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:95: warning: (520) function "_ADC1_SelectChannel" is never called
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:110: warning: (520) function "_ADC1_IsConversionDone" is never called
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:116: warning: (520) function "_ADC1_GetConversionResult" is never called
mcc_generated_files/adc1.c:122: warning: (520) function "_ADC1_GetConversion" is never called
mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.c:89: warning: (520) function "_PIN_MANAGER_IOC" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:108: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_StopTimer" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:114: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_ReadTimer" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:123: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_WriteTimer" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:145: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_Reload" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:152: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_StartSinglePulseAcquisition" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c:157: warning: (520) function "_TMR1_CheckGateValueStatus" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:94: warning: (520) function "_TMR0_ReadTimer" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:103: warning: (520) function "_TMR0_WriteTimer" is never called
mcc_generated_files/tmr0.c:109: warning: (520) function "_TMR0_Reload" is never called
Non line specific message:: warning: (2028) external declaration for identifier "_SD_STATE" doesn't indicate storage location
:0: error: (499) undefined symbol:
    _SD_STATE(dist/default/production\MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.obj) 
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:227: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AS/Desktop/MPLAB_Projekte/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:90: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/AS/Desktop/MPLAB_Projekte/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/MINIMAL_CO_Sensor_V04.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

I hope, you can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try placing volatile sd_state_t SD_STATE; in main.c. Maybe it needs somewhere to place the object into.

Answer (score 1):

You declare 4 extern variables in global.h

```
EXTERN volatile sd_state_t SD_STATE;
EXTERN volatile unsigned char gFlag_AdcReady;
EXTERN volatile unsigned char gFlag_SDAktiv; //  = 0;  The assign should go in .c
EXTERN volatile unsigned char gCnt_SD; // = 0;
```

You need to allocate space in one of your .c modules for these variables.  That's also where the initial value assignment goes. They will be set to zero automatically on boot.

```
volatile sd_state_t SD_STATE;
volatile unsigned char gFlag_AdcReady;
volatile unsigned char gFlag_SDAktiv;
volatile unsigned char gCnt_SD;
```